# Stable Scala 2.8 plugin

Tags: eclipse, scala, plugins, scala-2.8

Does anyone know if there exists a stable version of the Scala plugin for eclipse, running with Scala 2.8 (any version of scala 2.8...RC or beta or whatever).

I like the fact that it compiles 10 times faster than the netbeans plugin, but it is very unstable, and auto-imports doesnt work. Also, sometimes it cant find classes when I hit "run", then I have to clean it again. This is with some random nightly build of the 2.8 eclipse scala plugin.

Is there a stable version? If so, can you link me to it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main web site for Scala Eclipse plugin is now at [**www.scala-ide.org**](http://www.scala-ide.org/)

You can try the plugin for 2.8.0 RC2 with this [update p2 site](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/scala-plugin-rc/)
(not browsable: copy `http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/scala-plugin-rc/`)

As for a truly stable version, that plugin is not there yet, but as [Miles Sabin once told me](http://twitter.com/milessabin/status/3825931055) (Sept. 2009): "Looking forward to receiving your contributions."
And he was [quite snappy about it too](http://twitter.com/milessabin/status/3825972237) ;) But that was enough to convince my hierarchy that is was too early to invest in Scala at the time: too large eclipse user-base in our department, and no real Scala support/documentation at the time on Eclipse.
In all fairness, the contribution and [developer documentation](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developer_Documentation) is now much richer than it once was.

Comment: When you say copy, you mean that I should put it into eclipse's plugin downloader?

Comment: @Felix: I mean you register that address in the p2 update site list ("Install/Update", "Available Software Site" in the preferences), and then use it to (Help/"Install New software")

Comment: Thanks, it seems to fix the "class <name> not found" when running with f11, but auto-import still doesn't work. This is an important feature for me. Does this work for you with RC2 version of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it since release, and found 2.8.0 RC2 (link given by VonC) to be quite stable (certainly a lot more than 2.7.7).

Answer (score 0):

I was using eclipse 3.5.2 with the 2.8.0 RC2 plugin which created a lot of problems with compiling. I had to unistall the plugin and still the problems would remain. Only after a numbers of attempts to clean/build/delete/re-import the project and restart eclipse solved the problems...